# Android accessibility service FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY is deprecated

Tags: android, android-webview, accessibilityservice

Android accessibility service FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY is deprecated.
Does it have any alternative?

> FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY added in API level 18 int
>   FLAG_REQUEST_ENHANCED_WEB_ACCESSIBILITY This constant was deprecated
>   in API level 26. No longer used
>
> Constant Value: 8 (0x00000008)

Comment: The other question is, why has it been deprecated?